# Minikube failing to start in Centos 7.9

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

Full Minikube start command `minikube start --driver=docker --alsologtostderr -v=3`

Output:

```
minikube start --driver=docker --alsologtostderr -v=3
2022-10-10 15:03:12.668 | . I1010 13:03:11.656428   24138 out.go:296] Setting OutFile to fd 1 ...
2022-10-10 15:03:12.668 | . I1010 13:03:11.657466   24138 out.go:343] TERM=,COLORTERM=, which probably does not support color
2022-10-10 15:03:12.668 | . I1010 13:03:11.657488   24138 out.go:309] Setting ErrFile to fd 2...
2022-10-10 15:03:12.668 | . I1010 13:03:11.657526   24138 out.go:343] TERM=,COLORTERM=, which probably does not support color
2022-10-10 15:03:12.668 | . I1010 13:03:11.657771   24138 root.go:333] Updating PATH: /home/builder/.minikube/bin
2022-10-10 15:03:12.668 | . W1010 13:03:11.658273   24138 root.go:310] Error reading config file at /home/builder/.minikube/config/config.json: open /home/builder/.minikube/config/config.json: no such file or directory
2022-10-10 15:03:12.668 | . I1010 13:03:11.670761   24138 out.go:303] Setting JSON to false
2022-10-10 15:03:12.669 | . I1010 13:03:11.702854   24138 start.go:115] hostinfo: {"hostname":"vkvm1.eng.marklogic.com","uptime":359354,"bootTime":1665072838,"procs":189,"os":"linux","platform":"redhat","platformFamily":"rhel","platformVersion":"7.9","kernelVersion":"3.10.0-1160.76.1.el7.x86_64","kernelArch":"x86_64","virtualizationSystem":"","virtualizationRole":"guest","hostId":"8eb41075-ad46-4948-8bf3-6f56c8fc814f"}
2022-10-10 15:03:12.669 | . I1010 13:03:11.702985   24138 start.go:125] virtualization:  guest
2022-10-10 15:03:12.669 | . I1010 13:03:11.705293   24138 out.go:177] * minikube v1.27.0 on Redhat 7.9 (amd64)
2022-10-10 15:03:12.669 | . * minikube v1.27.0 on Redhat 7.9 (amd64)
2022-10-10 15:03:12.669 | . I1010 13:03:11.706999   24138 notify.go:214] Checking for updates...
2022-10-10 15:03:12.669 | . W1010 13:03:11.707409   24138 preload.go:295] Failed to list preload files: open /home/builder/.minikube/cache/preloaded-tarball: no such file or directory
2022-10-10 15:03:12.669 | . W1010 13:03:11.708033   24138 out.go:239] ! Kubernetes 1.25.0 has a known issue with resolv.conf. minikube is using a workaround that should work for most use cases.
2022-10-10 15:03:12.669 | . ! Kubernetes 1.25.0 has a known issue with resolv.conf. minikube is using a workaround that should work for most use cases.
2022-10-10 15:03:12.669 | . W1010 13:03:11.708170   24138 out.go:239] ! For more information, see: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/112135
2022-10-10 15:03:12.669 | . ! For more information, see: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/112135
2022-10-10 15:03:12.669 | . I1010 13:03:11.708304   24138 driver.go:365] Setting default libvirt URI to qemu:///system
2022-10-10 15:03:12.669 | . I1010 13:03:11.779753   24138 docker.go:137] docker version: linux-20.10.18
2022-10-10 15:03:12.669 | . I1010 13:03:11.780033   24138 cli_runner.go:164] Run: docker system info --format "{{json .}}"
2022-10-10 15:03:12.935 | . I1010 13:03:11.804722   24138 lock.go:35] WriteFile acquiring /home/builder/.minikube/last_update_check: {Name:mkfeeafdcd5b2a03a55be5c45e91f1633dbd4269 Clock:{} Delay:500ms Timeout:1m0s Cancel:<nil>}
2022-10-10 15:03:12.935 | . 
2022-10-10 15:03:12.936 | . I1010 13:03:11.957361   24138 info.go:265] docker info: {ID:U2TF:AUHN:IGPM:LOIS:LYU5:UDYQ:NGVO:W6RZ:NRM4:ZUBC:VRBL:C54T Containers:1 ContainersRunning:0 ContainersPaused:0 ContainersStopped:1 Images:1 Driver:overlay2 DriverStatus:[[Backing Filesystem xfs] [Supports d_type true] [Native Overlay Diff true] [userxattr false]] SystemStatus:<nil> Plugins:{Volume:[local] Network:[bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay] Authorization:<nil> Log:[awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog]} MemoryLimit:true SwapLimit:true KernelMemory:true KernelMemoryTCP:true CPUCfsPeriod:true CPUCfsQuota:true CPUShares:true CPUSet:true PidsLimit:true IPv4Forwarding:true BridgeNfIptables:true BridgeNfIP6Tables:true Debug:false NFd:24 OomKillDisable:true NGoroutines:34 SystemTime:2022-10-10 13:03:11.819053176 -0700 PDT LoggingDriver:json-file CgroupDriver:cgroupfs NEventsListener:0 KernelVersion:3.10.0-1160.76.1.el7.x86_64 OperatingSystem:Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.9 (Maipo) OSType:linux Architecture:x86_64 IndexServerAddress:https://index.docker.io/v1/ RegistryConfig:{AllowNondistributableArtifactsCIDRs:[] AllowNondistributableArtifactsHostnames:[] InsecureRegistryCIDRs:[127.0.0.0/8] IndexConfigs:{DockerIo:{Name:docker.io Mirrors:[] Secure:true Official:true}} Mirrors:[]} NCPU:4 MemTotal:16654606336 GenericResources:<nil> DockerRootDir:/space/docker HTTPProxy: HTTPSProxy: NoProxy: Name:vkvm1.eng.marklogic.com Labels:[] ExperimentalBuild:false ServerVersion:20.10.18 ClusterStore: ClusterAdvertise: Runtimes:{Runc:{Path:runc}} DefaultRuntime:runc Swarm:{NodeID: NodeAddr: LocalNodeState:inactive ControlAvailable:false Error: RemoteManagers:<nil>} LiveRestoreEnabled:false Isolation: InitBinary:docker-init ContainerdCommit:{ID:9cd3357b7fd7218e4aec3eae239db1f68a5a6ec6 Expected:9cd3357b7fd7218e4aec3eae239db1f68a5a6ec6} RuncCommit:{ID:v1.1.4-0-g5fd4c4d Expected:v1.1.4-0-g5fd4c4d} InitCommit:{ID:de40ad0 Expected:de40ad0} SecurityOptions:[name=seccomp,profile=default] ProductLicense: Warnings:<nil> ServerErrors:[] ClientInfo:{Debug:false Plugins:[map[Experimental:true Name:app Path:/usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-app SchemaVersion:0.1.0 ShortDescription:Docker App Vendor:Docker Inc. Version:v0.9.1-beta3] map[Name:buildx Path:/usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-buildx SchemaVersion:0.1.0 ShortDescription:Docker Buildx Vendor:Docker Inc. Version:v0.9.1-docker] map[Name:scan Path:/usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-scan SchemaVersion:0.1.0 ShortDescription:Docker Scan Vendor:Docker Inc. Version:v0.17.0]] Warnings:<nil>}}
2022-10-10 15:03:12.936 | . I1010 13:03:11.957632   24138 docker.go:254] overlay module found
2022-10-10 15:03:12.936 | . I1010 13:03:11.959650   24138 out.go:177] * Using the docker driver based on user configuration
2022-10-10 15:03:12.936 | . * Using the docker driver based on user configuration
2022-10-10 15:03:12.936 | . I1010 13:03:11.960738   24138 start.go:284] selected driver: docker
2022-10-10 15:03:12.936 | . I1010 13:03:11.960804   24138 start.go:808] validating driver "docker" against <nil>
2022-10-10 15:03:12.936 | . I1010 13:03:11.960861   24138 start.go:819] status for docker: {Installed:true Healthy:true Running:false NeedsImprovement:false Error:<nil> Reason: Fix: Doc: Version:}
2022-10-10 15:03:12.936 | . I1010 13:03:11.961184   24138 cli_runner.go:164] Run: docker system info --format "{{json .}}"
2022-10-10 15:03:13.209 | . I1010 13:03:12.105432   24138 info.go:265] docker info: {ID:U2TF:AUHN:IGPM:LOIS:LYU5:UDYQ:NGVO:W6RZ:NRM4:ZUBC:VRBL:C54T Containers:1 ContainersRunning:0 ContainersPaused:0 ContainersStopped:1 Images:1 Driver:overlay2 DriverStatus:[[Backing Filesystem xfs] [Supports d_type true] [Native Overlay Diff true] [userxattr false]] SystemStatus:<nil> Plugins:{Volume:[local] Network:[bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay] Authorization:<nil> Log:[awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog]} MemoryLimit:true SwapLimit:true KernelMemory:true KernelMemoryTCP:true CPUCfsPeriod:true CPUCfsQuota:true CPUShares:true CPUSet:true PidsLimit:true IPv4Forwarding:true BridgeNfIptables:true BridgeNfIP6Tables:true Debug:false NFd:24 OomKillDisable:true NGoroutines:34 SystemTime:2022-10-10 13:03:11.999402744 -0700 PDT LoggingDriver:json-file CgroupDriver:cgroupfs NEventsListener:0 KernelVersion:3.10.0-1160.76.1.el7.x86_64 OperatingSystem:Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.9 (Maipo) OSType:linux Architecture:x86_64 IndexServerAddress:https://index.docker.io/v1/ RegistryConfig:{AllowNondistributableArtifactsCIDRs:[] AllowNondistributableArtifactsHostnames:[] InsecureRegistryCIDRs:[127.0.0.0/8] IndexConfigs:{DockerIo:{Name:docker.io Mirrors:[] Secure:true Official:true}} Mirrors:[]} NCPU:4 MemTotal:16654606336 GenericResources:<nil> DockerRootDir:/space/docker HTTPProxy: HTTPSProxy: NoProxy: Name:vkvm1.eng.marklogic.com Labels:[] ExperimentalBuild:false ServerVersion:20.10.18 ClusterStore: ClusterAdvertise: Runtimes:{Runc:{Path:runc}} DefaultRuntime:runc Swarm:{NodeID: NodeAddr: LocalNodeState:inactive ControlAvailable:false Error: RemoteManagers:<nil>} LiveRestoreEnabled:false Isolation: InitBinary:docker-init ContainerdCommit:{ID:9cd3357b7fd7218e4aec3eae239db1f68a5a6ec6 Expected:9cd3357b7fd7218e4aec3eae239db1f68a5a6ec6} RuncCommit:{ID:v1.1.4-0-g5fd4c4d Expected:v1.1.4-0-g5fd4c4d} InitCommit:{ID:de40ad0 Expected:de40ad0} SecurityOptions:[name=seccomp,profile=default] ProductLicense: Warnings:<nil> ServerErrors:[] ClientInfo:{Debug:false Plugins:[map[Experimental:true Name:app Path:/usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-app SchemaVersion:0.1.0 ShortDescription:Docker App Vendor:Docker Inc. Version:v0.9.1-beta3] map[Name:buildx Path:/usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-buildx SchemaVersion:0.1.0 ShortDescription:Docker Buildx Vendor:Docker Inc. Version:v0.9.1-docker] map[Name:scan Path:/usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-scan SchemaVersion:0.1.0 ShortDescription:Docker Scan Vendor:Docker Inc. Version:v0.17.0]] Warnings:<nil>}}
2022-10-10 15:03:13.209 | . I1010 13:03:12.105750   24138 start_flags.go:296] no existing cluster config was found, will generate one from the flags 
2022-10-10 15:03:13.210 | . I1010 13:03:12.106519   24138 start_flags.go:377] Using suggested 3900MB memory alloc based on sys=15883MB, container=15883MB
2022-10-10 15:03:13.210 | . I1010 13:03:12.106744   24138 start_flags.go:835] Wait components to verify : map[apiserver:true system_pods:true]
2022-10-10 15:03:13.210 | . I1010 13:03:12.109246   24138 out.go:177] * Using Docker driver with root privileges
2022-10-10 15:03:13.210 | . * Using Docker driver with root privileges
2022-10-10 15:03:13.210 | . I1010 13:03:12.110491   24138 cni.go:95] Creating CNI manager for ""
2022-10-10 15:03:13.210 | . I1010 13:03:12.110542   24138 cni.go:169] CNI unnecessary in this configuration, recommending no CNI
2022-10-10 15:03:13.210 | . I1010 13:03:12.110582   24138 start_flags.go:310] config:
2022-10-10 15:03:13.210 | . {Name:minikube KeepContext:false EmbedCerts:false MinikubeISO: KicBaseImage:gcr.io/k8s-minikube/kicbase:v0.0.34@sha256:f2a1e577e43fd6769f35cdb938f6d21c3dacfd763062d119cade738fa244720c Memory:3900 CPUs:2 DiskSize:20000 VMDriver: Driver:docker HyperkitVpnKitSock: HyperkitVSockPorts:[] DockerEnv:[] ContainerVolumeMounts:[] InsecureRegistry:[] RegistryMirror:[] HostOnlyCIDR:192.168.59.1/24 HypervVirtualSwitch: HypervUseExternalSwitch:false HypervExternalAdapter: KVMNetwork:default KVMQemuURI:qemu:///system KVMGPU:false KVMHidden:false KVMNUMACount:1 APIServerPort:0 DockerOpt:[] DisableDriverMounts:false NFSShare:[] NFSSharesRoot:/nfsshares UUID: NoVTXCheck:false DNSProxy:false HostDNSResolver:true HostOnlyNicType:virtio NatNicType:virtio SSHIPAddress: SSHUser:root SSHKey: SSHPort:22 KubernetesConfig:{KubernetesVersion:v1.25.0 ClusterName:minikube Namespace:default APIServerName:minikubeCA APIServerNames:[] APIServerIPs:[] DNSDomain:cluster.local ContainerRuntime:docker CRISocket: NetworkPlugin: FeatureGates: ServiceCIDR:10.96.0.0/12 ImageRepository: LoadBalancerStartIP: LoadBalancerEndIP: CustomIngressCert: RegistryAliases: ExtraOptions:[] ShouldLoadCachedImages:true EnableDefaultCNI:false CNI: NodeIP: NodePort:8443 NodeName:} Nodes:[] Addons:map[] CustomAddonImages:map[] CustomAddonRegistries:map[] VerifyComponents:map[apiserver:true system_pods:true] StartHostTimeout:6m0s ScheduledStop:<nil> ExposedPorts:[] ListenAddress: Network: Subnet: MultiNodeRequested:false ExtraDisks:0 CertExpiration:26280h0m0s Mount:false MountString:/home/builder:/minikube-host Mount9PVersion:9p2000.L MountGID:docker MountIP: MountMSize:262144 MountOptions:[] MountPort:0 MountType:9p MountUID:docker BinaryMirror: DisableOptimizations:false DisableMetrics:false CustomQemuFirmwarePath:}
2022-10-10 15:03:13.210 | . I1010 13:03:12.112214   24138 out.go:177] * Starting control plane node minikube in cluster minikube
2022-10-10 15:03:13.210 | . * Starting control plane node minikube in cluster minikube
2022-10-10 15:03:13.210 | . I1010 13:03:12.113593   24138 cache.go:120] Beginning downloading kic base image for docker with docker
2022-10-10 15:03:13.210 | . I1010 13:03:12.114952   24138 out.go:177] * Pulling base image ...
2022-10-10 15:03:13.210 | . * Pulling base image ...
... (lots of logs from pulling images removed as I hit max char limit)
2022-10-10 15:04:10.436 | . * Creating docker container (CPUs=2, Memory=3900MB) ...
2022-10-10 15:04:10.436 | . I1010 13:04:09.178221   24138 start.go:159] libmachine.API.Create for "minikube" (driver="docker")
2022-10-10 15:04:10.436 | . I1010 13:04:09.178329   24138 client.go:168] LocalClient.Create starting
2022-10-10 15:04:10.436 | . I1010 13:04:09.179098   24138 client.go:171] LocalClient.Create took 685.72µs
2022-10-10 15:04:12.358 | . I1010 13:04:11.181303   24138 ssh_runner.go:195] Run: sh -c "df -h /var | awk 'NR==2{print $5}'"
2022-10-10 15:04:12.358 | . I1010 13:04:11.181622   24138 cli_runner.go:164] Run: docker container inspect -f "'{{(index (index .NetworkSettings.Ports "22/tcp") 0).HostPort}}'" minikube
2022-10-10 15:04:12.358 | . W1010 13:04:11.224149   24138 cli_runner.go:211] docker container inspect -f "'{{(index (index .NetworkSettings.Ports "22/tcp") 0).HostPort}}'" minikube returned with exit code 1
2022-10-10 15:04:12.358 | . I1010 13:04:11.224495   24138 retry.go:31] will retry after 276.165072ms: new client: new client: Error creating new ssh host from driver: Error getting ssh port for driver: get ssh host-port: get port 22 for "minikube": docker container inspect -f "'{{(index (index .NetworkSettings.Ports "22/tcp") 0).HostPort}}'" minikube: exit status 1
2022-10-10 15:04:12.358 | . stdout:
2022-10-10 15:04:12.358 | . 
2022-10-10 15:04:12.358 | . 
2022-10-10 15:04:12.358 | . stderr:
2022-10-10 15:04:12.358 | . Error: No such container: minikube
2022-10-10 15:04:12.618 | . I1010 13:04:11.501210   24138 cli_runner.go:164] Run: docker container inspect -f "'{{(index (index .NetworkSettings.Ports "22/tcp") 0).HostPort}}'" minikube
2022-10-10 15:04:12.618 | . W1010 13:04:11.542666   24138 cli_runner.go:211] docker container inspect -f "'{{(index (index .NetworkSettings.Ports "22/tcp") 0).HostPort}}'" minikube returned with exit code 1
2022-10-10 15:04:12.618 | . I1010 13:04:11.542848   24138 retry.go:31] will retry after 540.190908ms: new client: new client: Error creating new ssh host from driver: Error getting ssh port for driver: get ssh host-port: get port 22 for "minikube": docker container inspect -f "'{{(index (index .NetworkSettings.Ports "22/tcp") 0).HostPort}}'" minikube: exit status 1
(repeated logs removed here due to char limit)
2022-10-10 15:04:15.676 | . stdout:
2022-10-10 15:04:15.676 | . 
2022-10-10 15:04:15.676 | . 
2022-10-10 15:04:15.676 | . stderr:
2022-10-10 15:04:15.676 | . Error: No such container: minikube
2022-10-10 15:04:15.676 | . I1010 13:04:14.569874   24138 start.go:128] duration metric: createHost completed in 5.395396901s
2022-10-10 15:04:15.676 | . I1010 13:04:14.569895   24138 start.go:83] releasing machines lock for "minikube", held for 5.396481666s
2022-10-10 15:04:15.676 | . W1010 13:04:14.569998   24138 start.go:602] error starting host: creating host: create: bootstrapping certificates: failed to acquire bootstrap client lock: %!v(MISSING) bad file descriptor
2022-10-10 15:04:15.676 | . I1010 13:04:14.570230   24138 cli_runner.go:164] Run: docker container inspect minikube --format={{.State.Status}}
2022-10-10 15:04:15.676 | . W1010 13:04:14.609043   24138 cli_runner.go:211] docker container inspect minikube --format={{.State.Status}} returned with exit code 1
2022-10-10 15:04:15.676 | . I1010 13:04:14.609181   24138 delete.go:46] couldn't inspect container "minikube" before deleting: unknown state "minikube": docker container inspect minikube --format={{.State.Status}}: exit status 1
2022-10-10 15:04:15.676 | . stdout:
2022-10-10 15:04:15.676 | . 
2022-10-10 15:04:15.676 | . 
2022-10-10 15:04:15.676 | . stderr:
2022-10-10 15:04:15.676 | . Error: No such container: minikube
2022-10-10 15:04:15.676 | . I1010 13:04:14.611918   24138 cli_runner.go:164] Run: sudo -n podman container inspect minikube --format={{.State.Status}}
2022-10-10 15:04:15.676 | . W1010 13:04:14.649788   24138 cli_runner.go:211] sudo -n podman container inspect minikube --format={{.State.Status}} returned with exit code 1
2022-10-10 15:04:15.676 | . I1010 13:04:14.649837   24138 delete.go:46] couldn't inspect container "minikube" before deleting: unknown state "minikube": sudo -n podman container inspect minikube --format={{.State.Status}}: exit status 1
2022-10-10 15:04:15.676 | . stdout:
2022-10-10 15:04:15.676 | . 
2022-10-10 15:04:15.676 | . stderr:
2022-10-10 15:04:15.676 | . sudo: a password is required
2022-10-10 15:04:15.676 | . W1010 13:04:14.649922   24138 start.go:607] delete host: Docker machine "minikube" does not exist. Use "docker-machine ls" to list machines. Use "docker-machine create" to add a new one.
2022-10-10 15:04:15.676 | . W1010 13:04:14.650376   24138 out.go:239] ! StartHost failed, but will try again: creating host: create: bootstrapping certificates: failed to acquire bootstrap client lock: %!v(MISSING) bad file descriptor
2022-10-10 15:04:15.676 | . ! StartHost failed, but will try again: creating host: create: bootstrapping certificates: failed to acquire bootstrap client lock: %!v(MISSING) bad file descriptor
2022-10-10 15:04:15.676 | . I1010 13:04:14.650435   24138 start.go:617] Will try again in 5 seconds ...
2022-10-10 15:04:20.953 | . I1010 13:04:19.653290   24138 start.go:364] acquiring machines lock for minikube: {Name:mke10511c9cb3816f0997f9cfc8a1716887d51cb Clock:{} Delay:500ms Timeout:10m0s Cancel:<nil>}
2022-10-10 15:04:20.953 | . I1010 13:04:19.653711   24138 start.go:368] acquired machines lock for "minikube" in 296.18µs
2022-10-10 15:04:20.954 | . I1010 13:04:19.653797   24138 start.go:93] Provisioning new machine with config: &{Name:minikube KeepContext:false EmbedCerts:false MinikubeISO: KicBaseImage:gcr.io/k8s-minikube/kicbase:v0.0.34@sha256:f2a1e577e43fd6769f35cdb938f6d21c3dacfd763062d119cade738fa244720c Memory:3900 CPUs:2 DiskSize:20000 VMDriver: Driver:docker HyperkitVpnKitSock: HyperkitVSockPorts:[] DockerEnv:[] ContainerVolumeMounts:[] InsecureRegistry:[] RegistryMirror:[] HostOnlyCIDR:192.168.59.1/24 HypervVirtualSwitch: HypervUseExternalSwitch:false HypervExternalAdapter: KVMNetwork:default KVMQemuURI:qemu:///system KVMGPU:false KVMHidden:false KVMNUMACount:1 APIServerPort:0 DockerOpt:[] DisableDriverMounts:false NFSShare:[] NFSSharesRoot:/nfsshares UUID: NoVTXCheck:false DNSProxy:false HostDNSResolver:true HostOnlyNicType:virtio NatNicType:virtio SSHIPAddress: SSHUser:root SSHKey: SSHPort:22 KubernetesConfig:{KubernetesVersion:v1.25.0 ClusterName:minikube Namespace:default APIServerName:minikubeCA APIServerNames:[] APIServerIPs:[] DNSDomain:cluster.local ContainerRuntime:docker CRISocket: NetworkPlugin: FeatureGates: ServiceCIDR:10.96.0.0/12 ImageRepository: LoadBalancerStartIP: LoadBalancerEndIP: CustomIngressCert: RegistryAliases: ExtraOptions:[] ShouldLoadCachedImages:true EnableDefaultCNI:false CNI: NodeIP: NodePort:8443 NodeName:} Nodes:[{Name: IP: Port:8443 KubernetesVersion:v1.25.0 ContainerRuntime:docker ControlPlane:true Worker:true}] Addons:map[] CustomAddonImages:map[] CustomAddonRegistries:map[] VerifyComponents:map[apiserver:true system_pods:true] StartHostTimeout:6m0s ScheduledStop:<nil> ExposedPorts:[] ListenAddress: Network: Subnet: MultiNodeRequested:false ExtraDisks:0 CertExpiration:26280h0m0s Mount:false MountString:/home/builder:/minikube-host Mount9PVersion:9p2000.L MountGID:docker MountIP: MountMSize:262144 MountOptions:[] MountPort:0 MountType:9p MountUID:docker BinaryMirror: DisableOptimizations:false DisableMetrics:false CustomQemuFirmwarePath:} &{Name: IP: Port:8443 KubernetesVersion:v1.25.0 ContainerRuntime:docker ControlPlane:true Worker:true}
2022-10-10 15:04:20.954 | . I1010 13:04:19.654129   24138 start.go:125] createHost starting for "" (driver="docker")
2022-10-10 15:04:20.954 | . I1010 13:04:19.656399   24138 out.go:204] * Creating docker container (CPUs=2, Memory=3900MB) ...
2022-10-10 15:04:20.954 | . * Creating docker container (CPUs=2, Memory=3900MB) ...
2022-10-10 15:04:20.954 | . I1010 13:04:19.656656   24138 start.go:159] libmachine.API.Create for "minikube" (driver="docker")
2022-10-10 15:04:20.954 | . I1010 13:04:19.656760   24138 client.go:168] LocalClient.Create starting
2022-10-10 15:04:20.954 | . I1010 13:04:19.656936   24138 client.go:171] LocalClient.Create took 155.782µs
2022-10-10 15:04:22.871 | . I1010 13:04:21.657412   24138 ssh_runner.go:195] Run: sh -c "df -h /var | awk 'NR==2{print $5}'"
2022-10-10 15:04:22.871 | . I1010 13:04:21.658965   24138 cli_runner.go:164] Run: docker container inspect -f "'{{(index (index .NetworkSettings.Ports "22/tcp") 0).HostPort}}'" minikube
2022-10-10 15:04:22.871 | . W1010 13:04:21.696755   24138 cli_runner.go:211] docker container inspect -f "'{{(index (index .NetworkSettings.Ports "22/tcp") 0).HostPort}}'" minikube returned with exit code 1
2022-10-10 15:04:22.871 | . I1010 13:04:21.696968   24138 retry.go:31] will retry after 200.227965ms: new client: new client: Error creating new ssh host from driver: Error getting ssh port for driver: get ssh host-port: get port 22 for "minikube": docker container inspect -f "'{{(index (index .NetworkSettings.Ports "22/tcp") 0).HostPort}}'" minikube: exit status 1
2022-10-10 15:04:22.871 | . stdout:
2022-10-10 15:04:22.871 | . 
2022-10-10 15:04:22.871 | . 
2022-10-10 15:04:22.871 | . stderr:
2022-10-10 15:04:22.871 | . Error: No such container: minikube
2022-10-10 15:04:22.871 | . I1010 13:04:21.897543   24138 cli_runner.go:164] Run: docker container inspect -f "'{{(index (index .NetworkSettings.Ports "22/tcp") 0).HostPort}}'" minikube
2022-10-10 15:04:22.871 | . W1010 13:04:21.936224   24138 cli_runner.go:211] docker container inspect -f "'{{(index (index .NetworkSettings.Ports "22/tcp") 0).HostPort}}'" minikube returned with exit code 1
2022-10-10 15:04:22.871 | . I1010 13:04:21.936374   24138 retry.go:31] will retry after 380.704736ms: new client: new client: Error creating new ssh host from driver: Error getting ssh port for driver: get ssh host-port: get port 22 for "minikube": docker container inspect -f "'{{(index (index .NetworkSettings.Ports "22/tcp") 0).HostPort}}'" minikube: exit status 1
(lines removed due to char limit)
2022-10-10 15:04:24.531 | . stdout:
2022-10-10 15:04:24.531 | . 
2022-10-10 15:04:24.531 | . 
2022-10-10 15:04:24.531 | . stderr:
2022-10-10 15:04:24.531 | . Error: No such container: minikube
2022-10-10 15:04:24.790 | . I1010 13:04:23.735213   24138 cli_runner.go:164] Run: docker container inspect -f "'{{(index (index .NetworkSettings.Ports "22/tcp") 0).HostPort}}'" minikube
2022-10-10 15:04:24.791 | . W1010 13:04:23.774692   24138 cli_runner.go:211] docker container inspect -f "'{{(index (index .NetworkSettings.Ports "22/tcp") 0).HostPort}}'" minikube returned with exit code 1
2022-10-10 15:04:24.791 | . I1010 13:04:23.774864   24138 retry.go:31] will retry after 545.000538ms: new client: new client: Error creating new ssh host from driver: Error getting ssh port for driver: get ssh host-port: get port 22 for "minikube": docker container inspect -f "'{{(index (index .NetworkSettings.Ports "22/tcp") 0).HostPort}}'" minikube: exit status 1
2022-10-10 15:04:24.791 | . stdout:
2022-10-10 15:04:24.791 | . 
2022-10-10 15:04:24.791 | . 
2022-10-10 15:04:24.791 | . stderr:
2022-10-10 15:04:24.791 | . Error: No such container: minikube
2022-10-10 15:04:25.361 | . I1010 13:04:24.320916   24138 cli_runner.go:164] Run: docker container inspect -f "'{{(index (index .NetworkSettings.Ports "22/tcp") 0).HostPort}}'" minikube
2022-10-10 15:04:25.361 | . W1010 13:04:24.359812   24138 cli_runner.go:211] docker container inspect -f "'{{(index (index .NetworkSettings.Ports "22/tcp") 0).HostPort}}'" minikube returned with exit code 1
2022-10-10 15:04:25.361 | . I1010 13:04:24.359995   24138 retry.go:31] will retry after 660.685065ms: new client: new client: Error creating new ssh host from driver: Error getting ssh port for driver: get ssh host-port: get port 22 for "minikube": docker container inspect -f "'{{(index (index .NetworkSettings.Ports "22/tcp") 0).HostPort}}'" minikube: exit status 1
2022-10-10 15:04:26.188 | . stdout:
2022-10-10 15:04:26.188 | . 
2022-10-10 15:04:26.188 | . 
2022-10-10 15:04:26.188 | . stderr:
2022-10-10 15:04:26.188 | . Error: No such container: minikube
2022-10-10 15:04:26.188 | . 
2022-10-10 15:04:26.188 | . W1010 13:04:25.061915   24138 start.go:247] error getting GiB of /var that is available: NewSession: new client: new client: Error creating new ssh host from driver: Error getting ssh port for driver: get ssh host-port: get port 22 for "minikube": docker container inspect -f "'{{(index (index .NetworkSettings.Ports "22/tcp") 0).HostPort}}'" minikube: exit status 1
2022-10-10 15:04:26.188 | . stdout:
2022-10-10 15:04:26.188 | . 
2022-10-10 15:04:26.188 | . 
2022-10-10 15:04:26.188 | . stderr:
2022-10-10 15:04:26.188 | . Error: No such container: minikube
2022-10-10 15:04:26.188 | . I1010 13:04:25.061939   24138 start.go:128] duration metric: createHost completed in 5.407782504s
2022-10-10 15:04:26.188 | . I1010 13:04:25.061969   24138 start.go:83] releasing machines lock for "minikube", held for 5.408232309s
2022-10-10 15:04:26.188 | . W1010 13:04:25.062386   24138 out.go:239] * Failed to start docker container. Running "minikube delete" may fix it: creating host: create: bootstrapping certificates: failed to acquire bootstrap client lock: %!v(MISSING) bad file descriptor
2022-10-10 15:04:26.188 | . * Failed to start docker container. Running "minikube delete" may fix it: creating host: create: bootstrapping certificates: failed to acquire bootstrap client lock: %!v(MISSING) bad file descriptor
2022-10-10 15:04:26.188 | . I1010 13:04:25.064746   24138 out.go:177] 
2022-10-10 15:04:26.188 | . 
2022-10-10 15:04:26.188 | . W1010 13:04:25.066259   24138 out.go:239] X Exiting due to GUEST_PROVISION_ACQUIRE_LOCK: Failed to start host: creating host: create: bootstrapping certificates: failed to acquire bootstrap client lock: %!v(MISSING) bad file descriptor
2022-10-10 15:04:26.188 | . X Exiting due to GUEST_PROVISION_ACQUIRE_LOCK: Failed to start host: creating host: create: bootstrapping certificates: failed to acquire bootstrap client lock: %!v(MISSING) bad file descriptor
2022-10-10 15:04:26.188 | . W1010 13:04:25.066434   24138 out.go:239] * Suggestion: Please try purging minikube using `minikube delete --all --purge`
2022-10-10 15:04:26.188 | . * Suggestion: Please try purging minikube using `minikube delete --all --purge`
2022-10-10 15:04:26.188 | . W1010 13:04:25.066568   24138 out.go:239] * Related issue: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/11022
2022-10-10 15:04:26.188 | . * Related issue: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/11022
2022-10-10 15:04:26.188 | . I1010 13:04:25.067905   24138 out.go:177]
```

I have tried running just the docker image and it works fine, I've tried purging minikube as it recommends and that has not solved the issue. I've also tried setting the MINIKUBE_HOME variable. I'm pretty new to K8S on centos7 so any advice would be greatly apreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by setting MINIKUBE_HOME variable to a value outside of the home directory. This github issue helped in solving this: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/11022#issuecomment-848387322